# Mysterious TransactionConflict in TransactionCanceledException

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Using [transactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#transactWriteItems-property) in the aws-sdk (js) we get a [TransactionCanceledException](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactGetItems.html#API_TransactGetItems_Errors). The reason within that Exception is given as **TransactionConflict**. Sometimes all actions in the transaction fail, sometimes only a few or only one. We do run multiple transactions in parallel that can operate on the same items. The documentation doesn't mention this particular error. Possible reason excerpt:

> 1. A condition in one of the condition expressions is not met.
> 2. A table in the TransactWriteItems request is in a different account or
>      region.
> 3. More than one action in the TransactWriteItems operation targets the
>      same item.
> 4. There is insufficient provisioned capacity for the transaction to be
>      completed.
> 5. An item size becomes too large (larger than 400 KB), or a local
>      secondary index (LSI) becomes too large, or a similar validation error
>      occurs because of changes made by the transaction.
> 6. There is a user error, such as an invalid data format.

None of these apply and when retrying the transaction it seems to eventually work. Anyone knows about this exception? I can't find anything documented.

Comment: TransactionConflict seems like it would imply #3, and you mentioned that you do run multiple parallel transactions that can operate on the same items. If it’s due to a conflict, then retrying would eventually work, which is what you have said is happening. Are you sure that it isn’t #3?

Comment: @MatthewPope #3 talks about the TransactWriteItems. These are items in the same transaction, not in different transactions. So yes, I'm pretty sure it isn't #3. Nothing is mentioned on parallel transactions being an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I misread #3. Still, the way transactions (in general) work is that they basically lock the items in the request. A transaction conflict would likely mean that there was another operation that conflicted with the transaction.

Comment: @MatthewPope See, I would assume that as well. However historically Dynamodb didn't really have any write conflicts to deal with (similar to s3). I doubt AWS would just quietly add them with the new transaction feature without mentioning it. So possibly a bug. I'll try an post on their forum next.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you are experiencing is not a bug—it’s actually part of the feature, and it was mentioned in the [launch announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/) .

> Items are not locked during a transaction. DynamoDB transactions provide serializable isolation. If an item is modified outside of a transaction while the transaction is in progress, the transaction is canceled and an exception is thrown with details about which item or items caused the exception.

As an aside, instead of locking, DynamoDB uses something called optimistic concurrency control (which is also (confusingly) called optimistic locking). If you’re interested in learning more about that, the Wikipedia article on [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) is pretty good.

Back to the matter at hand, the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html) for transactions says:

> Multiple transactions updating the same items simultaneously can cause conflicts that cancel the transactions. We recommend following DynamoDB best practices for data modeling to minimize such conflicts.

Specifically for TransactWriteItems, they say:

> Write transactions don't succeed under the following circumstances:
>
> When an ongoing TransactWriteItems operation conflicts with a concurrent TransactWriteItems request on one or more items in the TransactWriteItems operation. In this case, the concurrent request fails with a TransactionCancelledException

Similarly for TransactGetItems:

> Read transactions don't succeed under the following circumstances:
>
> When there is an ongoing TransactGetItems operation that conflicts with a concurrent PutItem, UpdateItem, DeleteItem or TransactWriteItems request. In this case the TransactGetItems operation fails with a TransactionCancelledException

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally missed that when I was scanning though the docs. At least the next person running into the error will have this ticket as a reference now! Cheers!

Comment: This is annoying.. I expected Dynamo to enqueue the requests to the same item instead of throwing an error.. I have a voting app where I keep updating the amount of votes like this `ADD upVotes = upVotes + 1`, and I started to see a lot of these transaction cancelled errors when load testing... Just introduced some retries with exponential backoffs, lets see if this helps...

Comment: @RenatoGama I'm using a similar UpdateExpression in my transaction (consisting of a Put item and an Update item: the Put item puts data in one table, and the Update item updates a counter dictionary, by hour, of things that are put into the first table, in a second table)... I also added retries in exponential backoffs before coming to this post... Still having the problem. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @user3773048 after adding retries it worked really well for me. Maybe you have more load then me to a point it won't help at all :(

Comment: @RenatoGama Hm, yeah, I've put that problem aside for now, planning on returning to it later. Some minutes I get ~80k invocations. Usually in the day it peaks around 35k invocations. I imagine there's some magic I can throw at this, like redis or SNS streams somehow, or maybe I just figure out if I can make custom metrics for basically creating a count using Cloudwatch, if that's a thing... I'm seeing about 2% less in count from what's getting sent to the downstream system, but I want to have a solid source of truth (though not currently critical), so will look into it more later.

Comment: @RenatoGama the weird thing is that it's only about 2% off, and the exponential back-off goes for about 3 hours (or 1.5 hours if I mis-calculated). I get peaks of traffic then nothing, every few hours. So I imagine that should be working. Anyways...

Comment: What is the best dynamodb practice to avoid transactionConflict when, for example, the same item needs to be updated thousands of times?
Example: there is a wallet that needs to update the available balance for each transaction.

Comment: What is the best dynamodb practice to avoid transactionConflict when, for example, the same item needs to be updated thousands of times? Example: there is a wallet that needs to update the available balance for each transaction.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error with transactWriteItems. Yes I can see there has been 2 concurrent operations at the time accessing same record. I'm going to add retries in exponential backoffs.